# Complex numbers: $ (\sqrt{3}+ i)^{30} $ to 'a + ib' form

Tags: complex-numbers

How do I rewrite this to 'a + ib' form? The power of 30 is troubling me.

$ (\sqrt{3}+ i)^{30} $

Comment: Switch to the polar form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint. Since $|\sqrt{3}+i|=2$, we have that
$$(\sqrt{3}+ i)^{30}=2^{30}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+ \frac{i}{2}\right)^{30}=2^{30}\left(\cos(\pi/6)+ i\sin(\pi/6)\right)^{30}.$$
Then use [De Moivre's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula).

Comment: Hmm, but how did you figure out you had to divide by 2?

Comment: @javanewbie Because $|\sqrt{3}+i|=2$.

Comment: I am just learning about complex numbers so excuse my ignorance, but I still don't quite understand. Why it was specifically the number 2 I understand now, but why divide it by anything? And how does it translate into the last part?

Comment: In order to use De Moivre's Formula you should have a complex number of modulus one that is $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+ \frac{i}{2}$. Then any complex number of modulus one can be written as $\cos(\theta) +i\sin(\theta)$ for some angle $\theta$ (the argument).

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number for more details

Comment: Yes but not sure if I'm just not understanding out of stupidity, heh. But what do you mean by 'number of modulus one' (English isn't exactly my first language so the terminology varies a bit)

Comment: @javanewbie "Modulus" is the same of "absolute value". The absolute value of $z=x+iy$ is $|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Absolute_value_and_argument

Answer (score 5):

"By hand":

$$(\sqrt3+i)^2=3-1+i2\sqrt3=2(1+i\sqrt3)$$

$$(\sqrt3+i)^3=2(1+i\sqrt3)(\sqrt3+i)=8i.$$

Then

$$(\sqrt3+i)^{30}=(8i)^{10}=(-64)^5=-1073741824.$$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint.** Use exponential/polar form
$$\sqrt{3}+i = 2e^{\frac{\pi}{6}i}.$$